# rotated text in sidebar - css

Tags: html, css, transform, responsive

I want to make a sidebar where the text is rotated and centered inside the sidebar. I want this in text and css, not  background image or something...
How would something like this be done in css?

[image]

I have tried to use `transform: rotate(7deg);` and stuff, but I can't position it correctly.
[Here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/NicolasV/pen/oLNZed) with the basic structure. The topbar should be on the left side of the screen (like in the picture).

This also has to be responsive. And when you click the menu toggle the sidebar slides open so the text should be easily hidden with some css/js.

Thanks

**ANSWERED:**
The answer from @darrylyeo was the right fix for me. Much simpeler to make up the div as you would (horizontally) and then rotate the whole div.
Rotation text inside a div seemed to be more difficult to position right all the responsive breakpoints.

Comment: This question is too broad. Too many possible answers.

Comment: @Nicolas V Please put your code with the question

Comment: your question is unclear , what do you mean by rotated text ?

Comment: @Srinivas08 I want to rotate the text like shown in the picture.. Not sure what is unclear about that!

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil that is why I am here.. I have no clue how to do this. I added a basic codepen in original post

Comment: I made this before a few days, for footer, but it could be used for menu/sidebar, too, i hope: https://jsfiddle.net/r78u6evL/1/

Comment: @Nicolas V Your question is not clear for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Positioning With Transforms: The Process

1. Determine what the dimensions are, *before* any transformations.
2. Choose an anchor point, or origin, to base the transformation on. Finding the **best** anchor point for your purpose may take some trial and error.
3. Based on that anchor point, figure out where to position the element.
4. Finally, apply the transformation.

---

## First Attempt

```
.sidebar {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 60px;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 60px;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

### Explanation

To visualize this best, add one property at a time in order as listed.

- Apply a background color so we can see where the side bar is.
- Set the width to 100% the *height* of the viewport.
- Set the height to (say) 60 pixels.
- Position absolutely (`fixed` would work as well).
- Set the transformation anchor point to the *bottom left* corner.
- Position 60 pixels from the left (or whatever you set the height to be), and 0 pixels from the bottom.
- Now, rotate around the anchor point counterclockwise by 90 degrees.

### Downside

You can't adjust `height` without having to change `left` accordingly.

---

## Better Attempt

```
.sidebar {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 60px;
    transform-origin: top left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

### Explanation

Same as the first solution, except:

- Set the transformation anchor point to the *top left* corner.
- Position 0 pixels from the left, and *100%* from the top. This means that the top of the element touches the bottom of the viewport.
- Now, rotate around the anchor point counterclockwise by 90 degrees.

Now, to expand the sidebar, we have only to change one property: `height`.

Comment: This worked! I had transform rotation only on text, never though about rotating the whole div. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, I can definitely see how transforming the text only would prove to be much trickier. I'm glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

You will achieve this with some JS the easiest.
Click Event the the Menu trigger, and then the eventhandler function to animate the menu on and off screen. For the rotate text functionality, if I understood properly what you want, all you need is this:

```
#menu li {
margin-top: 3px;
font-size: 14pt;
transition:.5s;
}
li:hover{
-webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
transform: rotateX(360deg);}
```

Here the link to a code pen, click the pink top left menu logo and then hover over the list items.

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/XXbymL

Comment: The animation to slide it in from the left I had already written. Although your codepen looks cleaner. Will definitely change my code with yours in mind.